# No padding for hours in strftime

Tags: ruby, strftime

When using `strftime @tzformat = "%F,%l:00 %p"`:

I want exactly one space between the comma and the hour. But `%l` gives no space for 10, 11 and 12 whereas if I put `“ %l”` I get two spaces for 0-9 (one from the padding and another from the space I add).

Month has no-padding option. I don’t see the same for hour.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show us your input data and the expected output along with an example of your code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The - modifier removes padding. If you use %-l instead of %l it will not put a space at all, and you can manually add a space.

```
Time.now.strftime @tzformat = "%F, %-l:00 %p"            #=> "2015-01-29, 8:00 PM"
(Time.now + 3600*2).strftime @tzformat = "%F, %-l:00 %p" #=> "2015-01-29, 10:00 PM"
```

Comment: Thanks Dane. So, what I was missing was that there is no example in the hours section of http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime like there is for month. I should have read the intro text, not just the examples!